# number of bound variables does not match number of token

Tags: php, mysql

I created a php page which gonna save a record into a database, this is the code I wrote :

```
try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tp_js_php','root','');
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    //Selectionner la table de clients
          $reponse = $bdd->query('Select * from client');
          $clients = $reponse->fetchAll();

try
            {
            $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO client(nomClient,PrenomClient,Adresse,Télephone,Email,Pseudo,MotDePasse) VALUES (:nom, :prenom, :adresse, :tel, :email, :pseudo, :mdp)');
            $req->execute(array(
                    ':nom' => $_POST['nom'],
                    ':prenom', $_POST['prenom'],
                    ':adresse', $_POST['adresse'],
                    ':tel', $_POST['telephone'],
                    ':email', $_POST['email'],
                    ':pseudo', $_POST['pseudo'],
                    ':mdp', sha1($_POST['mdp'])));
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
```

this is the error I got :

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\tp_fomulaire_js\insertion.php on line 21
```

the line 21 is : `':mdp', sha1($_POST['mdp'])));`

I count all the parametres an no one is messing except the idClient which is incremental.

Comment: You have 7 place-holders but you are passing 13 parameters. Read Yogesh's answer if you can't spot why :)

Answer (score 3):

use this code, you have to use `=>` , but you used `,`.

```
$req->execute(array(
                ':nom' => $_POST['nom'],
                ':prenom' => $_POST['prenom'],
                ':adresse' => $_POST['adresse'],
                ':tel' => $_POST['telephone'],
                ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                ':pseudo' => $_POST['pseudo'],
                ':mdp' => sha1($_POST['mdp'])));
```

Comment: I have did your correction, but I got this new error : Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\tp_fomulaire_js\insertion.php on line 14

Comment: @SuSha what is the line no. 14? show it's code.

Comment: it was a syntax error I have corrected it, but even of these modifications I can't find the new record on the database